# export student result in php to excel

Tags: php, html, excel, web, export

I made a Student Result page. I wanted to export the results to excel. For that I made excel.php. When I click on the export button it is showing that there is no results. But results are showing in the webpage. Please find the attached screenshot of results and help me to solve the issue.

[image: Screenshot of Results in webpage]

rsltmng.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once '../oesdb.php';
/************************** Step 1 *************************/
if(!isset($_SESSION['admname'])) {
    $_GLOBALS['message']="Session Timeout.Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    /************************** Step 2 - Case 1 *************************/
    //Log out and redirect login page
        unset($_SESSION['admname']);
        header('Location: index.php');

    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['dashboard'])) {
    /************************** Step 2 - Case 2 *************************/
        //redirect to dashboard
            header('Location: admwelcome.php');

        }
        else if(isset($_REQUEST['back'])) {
    /************************** Step 2 - Case 3s *************************/
            //redirect to Result Management
                header('Location: rsltmng.php');    
            }    
?>  


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<title>Manage Results - OES</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="logmsk" style="display: block;">
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="page3">
<form name="rsltmng" action="rsltmng.php" method="post">

<div id="navigationbar">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['admname'])) {
                        // Navigations

                            ?>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout" class="aclass2" title="Log Out"/></li>
                            <?php  if(isset($_REQUEST['testid'])) { ?>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="Back" name="back" class="aclass2" title="Manage Results"/></li>
                            <?php }else { ?>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="DashBoard" name="dashboard" class="aclass3" title="Dash Board"/></li>
                            <?php } ?>
</div>
<div><p style="font-weight:bold; color:#F00; text-align:center"><?php if($_GLOBALS['message']){ echo ($_GLOBALS['message']);}?></p></div>

<?php
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['testid'])) {
 /************************** Step 3 - Case 1 *************************/
 // Defualt Mode: Displays the Detailed Test Results.
                            $result=executeQuery("select t.testname,DATE_FORMAT(t.testfrom,'%d %M %Y') as fromdate,DATE_FORMAT(t.testto,'%d %M %Y %H:%i:%S') as todate,sub.subname,IFNULL((select sum(marks) from question where testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']."),0) as maxmarks from test as t, subject as sub where sub.subid=t.subid and t.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid'].";") ;
                            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) {

                                $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                ?>
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" border="0" align="center" style="background:#ffffff url(../images/page.gif);text-align:left;line-height:20px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="color:#0000cc;text-align:center;"><u>Test Summary</u></h3></td>
                        </tr>
                       <!-- <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" ><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:4px;"/></td>
                        </tr>-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test Name:</td>
                            <td><b><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['testname'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Subject Name:</td>
                            <td><b><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['subname'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Validity:</td>
                            <td><b><?php echo $r['fromdate']." To ".$r['todate']; ?></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Max. Marks:</td>
                            <td><b><?php echo $r['maxmarks']; ?></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:2px;"/></td></tr>
                        <!--<tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="color:#0000cc;text-align:center;">Attempted Students</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" ><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:4px;"/></td>
                        </tr>-->

                    </table>
                    <table><tr><td><h3 style="color:#0000cc;text-align:center;"><u>Attempted Students</u></h3></td></tr></table>                 

                                <?php
                                $result1=executeQuery("select s.fname,s.contactno,s.emailid,IFNULL((select sum(q.marks) as om from studentquestion as sq, question as q where sq.testid=q.testid and sq.qnid=q.qnid and sq.answered='answered' and sq.stdanswer=q.correctanswer and sq.stdid=st.stdid and sq.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." order by sq.testid),0) as om from studenttest as st, student as s where s.stdid=st.stdid and st.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']."  order by om DESC;" );


                                if(mysql_num_rows($result1)==0) {
                                    echo"<h3 style=\"color:#0000cc;text-align:center;\">No Students Yet Attempted this Test!</h3>";
                                }
                                else {
                                    ?>

                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" class="datatable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student Name</th>
                            <th>Contact Number</th>
                            <th>Email-ID</th>
                            <th>Obtained Marks</th>
                            <th>Result(%)</th>

                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                        while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

                                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['fname'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['contactno'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r1['emailid'],ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r1['om']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo ($r1['om']/$r['maxmarks']*100)." %"; ?></td>


                        </tr>

                        <form method="post" action="excel.php"><input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="aclass3" value="Export Result" /></form>
                                        <?php

                                        }    
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo"<h3 style=\"color:#0000cc;text-align:center;\">Something went wrong. Please logout and Try again.</h3>";
                                }
                                ?>
                    </table>       
                        <?php    
                        }
                        else {

                        /************************** Step 3 - Case 2 *************************/
                        // Defualt Mode: Displays the Test Results.
                            $result=executeQuery("select t.testid,t.testname,DATE_FORMAT(t.testfrom,'%d %M %Y') as fromdate,DATE_FORMAT(t.testto,'%d %M %Y %H:%i:%S') as todate,sub.subname,(select count(stdid) from studenttest where testid=t.testid) as attemptedstudents from test as t, subject as sub where sub.subid=t.subid;");
                            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
                                echo "<h3 style=\"color:#0000cc;text-align:center;\">No Tests Yet...!</h3>";
                            }
                            else {
                                $i=0;

                                ?>
                    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" class="datatable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Test Name</th>
                            <th>Validity</th>
                            <th>Subject Name</th>
                            <th>Attempted Students</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
            <?php
                                    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        $i=$i+1;
                                        if($i%2==0) {
                                            echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
                                        }
                                        else { echo "<tr>";}
                                        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars_decode($r['testname'],ENT_QUOTES)."</td><td>".$r['fromdate']." To ".$r['todate']." PM </td>"
                                            ."<td>".htmlspecialchars_decode($r['subname'],ENT_QUOTES)."</td><td>".$r['attemptedstudents']."</td>"
                                            ."<td class=\"tddata\"><a title=\"Details\" href=\"rsltmng.php?testid=".$r['testid']."\"><img src=\"../images/detail.png\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Details\" /></a></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                    </table>
        <?php
                            }
                        }
                        closedb();
                    }

                    ?>


</form>
</div>
<div  style="position: relative; clear:both; z-index:10; height:3em; margin-top:-3em"><?php include("footer.php"); ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

excel.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ssmc_ae_drsunny");
$output = '';
$_REQUEST['testid']=isset($_REQUEST['testid']);

if(isset($_POST["export_excel"]))
{

$sql=executeQuery("select s.fname,s.contactno,s.emailid,IFNULL((select sum(q.marks) as om from studentquestion as sq, question as q where sq.testid=q.testid and sq.qnid=q.qnid and sq.answered='answered' and sq.stdanswer=q.correctanswer and sq.stdid=st.stdid and sq.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']." order by sq.testid),0) as om from studenttest as st, student as s where s.stdid=st.stdid and st.testid=".$_REQUEST['testid']."  order by om DESC;" );   
    $result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
        $output .= '
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" class="datatable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student Name</th>
                            <th>Contact Number</th>
                            <th>Email-ID</th>
                            <th>Obtained Marks</th>
                            <th>Result(%)</th>

                        </tr>
                        ';
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        $output .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row['fname'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['contactno'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['emailid'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['om'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['om'].'/'.$row['maxmarks'].'*100."%"</td>
                        </tr>
                        ';  
                        }
                        $output .= '</table>';
                        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
                        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
                        echo $output;       
    }
    else
    {echo "NO RESULT"; }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors (on page or in your error log)? Is the page completely blank? Is it actually working but it's downloading the file (check your browser downloads)? Do you realise you're outputting HTML to an XLS file?

Comment: Page showing no results

Comment: I think you need to remove the `executeQuery` part in excel.php

Comment: I tried. but still showing NO RESULT.

Comment: Consider writing an [mvce] to corner your problem out. Here if you post your whole project, it can be a little difficult for people to follow your mind. It's kind of "off-topic".

Comment: I want to export the result to excel. For that, I made a button to export. It uses export.php. when I click the button it is showing NO RESULT. That is my problem. I just want to how to solve the issue.

Comment: Any solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
$_REQUEST['testid']=isset($_REQUEST['testid']);
```

This line actually makes the `$_REQUEST['testid']` variable into 1 or 0.

So the query gets executed but no result gets displayed as there is no such row int the table.

Comment: Just replace the line. That line is not needed.Msg me on Whatsapp if you dont understand (+919092943926)

Comment: Still not working. Is there any other way to export datas from

Comment: Still not working. Is there any other way to export datas from <table> to excel?. Please give me a solution for this.